# Issue on Tomcat 5.5 server while accessing application in secure mode

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using `Tomcat 5.5` & `JDK 1.5.0_21`. Tomcat 5.5 is successful started. I need to access tomcat in secure mode, but not able to access the application using 'https:localhost' but able to access as 'http:localhost:portno.'.

The SSL settings is as below :

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
        <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" port="8080" redirectPort="443"/>

<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile=".keystore" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" port="443" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Would there be any other server setting issue or browser settings i need to check for ? Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which port number you are using in `https` url?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the SSL configuration.
`port="443"`
Change it to `port="8443"`